# Displaying location request prompt when user denies the location

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

What is a proper way to handle situation when user denies to track his location and the whole app is based on current location? I'm calling a `locationAuthorization()` in viewDidAppear and it works fine when the user allows the location.

```
func locationAuthorization(){
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse{
        refreshData()

    } else if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied) {
        addressButton.isHidden = true
    } else {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        sleep(2)
        locationAuthorization()
    }
}
```

I was trying to call the `locationAuthorization()` inside the .denied statement but it obviously didn't work. Putting `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` didn't work neither.
So what's the best way to handle the situation when user clicks "Don't allow"? It makes my app unusable so I have to display the location window until the user accepts it.

Comment: Your logic for requesting authorization, sleeping, then calling `locationAuthorization` again is terrible. Please do not do it that way.

Comment: And you need to handle the other cases properly. Only request authorization when it is currently unknown. You are requesting even when restricted. That's kind of pointless.

Comment: @rmaddy I know that the sleep is not the best option but it didn't work without it.

Comment: Use the appropriate delegate method to be told when the authorization changes.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for help. I used locationManager(... didChangeAuthorization) and then added the alert to get to the settings and now it works without sleep and other weird methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place this in the `.denied` part:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Need Authorization", message: "This app is unusable if you don't authorize this app to use your location!", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: { _ in
    let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can't request for authorization again, but you can tell people to change it in settings.

Comment: I'd label the "OK" button as "Settings" and the "No" button as "Cancel".